# Would the following code go into the if statement

Tags: python

```
x = None
if not x:
   do_something()
```

^ Since x is None, will it enter the if statement?

Comment: `None` is a python singleton. `null` in Java describes no memory address.

Comment: there is no check in if statement on x value

Comment: Sorry, I am so error prone: I hope it makes sense now lol.

Comment: Coming from Java, remember you can always use Python interactive shell to try such small things.

Comment: Anyways thanks for all of your help, everyone!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python has no value called `null`, so your question doesn't make sense.  `x == null` will raise a NameError.

Answer to your updated question: Yes, it will enter the if statement.  `None` is false in a boolean context, so `not None` is true.  You can see this yourself in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> not None
True
```

If you're coming from a Java background, you should realize that Python makes it much easier to try things out.  Get used to trying things in the Python interpreter.  A lot of questions can easily be answered just by trying things yourself and seeing what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Python, coming from a Java background, so I forgot about this, I have updated the question.

Comment: @RohitRayudu: I've edited my answer to address your updated question.